# Transform translate property does not work using calc in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am facing a problem using calc in Internet explorer.
I am using `transform: translate(calc(-50% + 10px), calc(-50% + 20px))` which does not work in Internet Explorer.

I am aware that 
`transform: translate(0, calc(100% + 5px))` does not work in Internet Explorer but is eqivalent to `transform: translate(0, 100%) translate(0, 5px)` which Works in IE.

Can someone help with `transform: translate(calc(-50% + 10px), calc(-50% + 20px))` converting it equivalent so that it works in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Just split it up into different translations:

```
   transform: translateX(-50%)
              translateX(10px)
              translateY(-50%)
              translateY(20px);
```